# SQL Query Joining 2 Tables and Getting Required Data

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 Tables:
Merchant having 3 columns MerchantID, MemberID, MerchantName
Member having 3 columns MemberID, ReportID, MemberName

The sample values are:

```
MerchantID MemberID MerchantName
1101       101      ABC
1102       102      DEF
1103       103      XYZ

MemberID   ReportID MemberName
101        112      GHI
101        111      JKL
101        115      MNO
102        111      kjh
102        116      hgf
102        117      oiu
103        118      hgh
103        119      jhf
```

I need to get the MerchantNames which have Member IDs that are not associated with 111 Report ID.

```
The query o/p should be: XYZ.
```

Kindly let me know the most optimized SQL query which can achieve this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried something with NOT IN but that never returned the required o/p. Missed out on using the NOT EXISTS, which works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: I know you have a working solution now, but just thought I'd point out that NOT IN should work in this scenario too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic usecase for the `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT MerchantName
FROM   Merchant
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Member
                   WHERE  Member.MemberId = Merchant.MemberId AND 
                          ReportId = 111)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply !

Comment: Did you know that Oracle had to add special code to handle the incorrect `SELECT 1` because of the urban legend all over the internet that this was better than the correct `SELECT *`? So, `SELECT 1` works, but I still cringe to see it. It should never have lived.

Answer (score 1):

with JOIN:

```
SELECT mer.MerchantName FROM [Merchant] mer
 LEFT JOIN [Member] mem ON mer.MemberId = mem.MemberId
  AND mem.ReportId != 111;
```

Or

```
SELECT mer.MerchantName FROM [Merchant] mer
 LEFT JOIN [Member] mem ON mer.MemberId = mem.MemberId
  AND mem.ReportId <> 111;
```